# connected components using Breadth first search

Tags: python, graph-algorithm, breadth-first-search, connected-components

I need to find the connected components of a graph. 
I have a neighbour list of nodes:

```
neighbour_list = [[4], [2, 5], [1, 3, 8], [2, 14], [0, 9], [1], [10, 12], [13], [2, 14], [4, 10, 15], [6, 9], [17], [6], [7, 19, 20], [3, 8], [9, 21], [22], [11, 18], [17, 19], [13, 18, 26], [13, 26], [15, 27], [16, 23], [22, 24, 28], [23, 25, 29], [24], [19, 20, 30, 31], [21], [23, 29], [24, 28], [26, 31], [26, 30]]
```

For example node 0 has neighbour 4, node 1 has neighbours 2 and 5 etc...
What I want to find is a list of connected components. Say node 0 has neighbour 4, yet neighbour 4 also is a neighbour of node 9. Node 9 also has number 10 and 15  neighbours. So the list would be something like

```
[4,10,15....] etc including following neihbours.
```

the method I am trying to use is breadth first search.
I wrote the following algorithm:

```
 def bfs(neighbour_list, node):

    label_list =[]   
    for sub_neighbour_list in neighbour_list: 

      label_list.append(node)

      queue = [node]

    while queue:
        u = queue[0]
        for sub_neighbour in neighbour_list[u]:
           if sub_neighbour not in queue:
             label_list[sub_neighbour] = 0
             queue.append(sub_neighbour)
             queue.pop(0)

   print(label_list)
   return (label_list)
```

nothing happens when I run it. What is wrong?

thanks

Comment: Indent the three lines following the "if" statement, and all of the lines after the first "for" up to but not including the "print" statement.

Comment: @Marichyasana still doesnt do anything

Comment: Where's `sub_neighbour_list` being defined?

Comment: Can you show us what parameters you're calling it with, and update the formatting of the originsal question code?

Comment: You pass in a parameter `node` but then your line `for node in sub_neighbour_list in neighbour_list:` redefines `node`. So you lose the original node you were looking for.

Comment: I'd also expect `label_list = []` followed by `label_list[node] = 0` would give an `IndexError`...

Comment: In addition to jedwards' answer I would suggest to use the data structure deque `from collections import deque` and then `queue = deque()` and `queue.popleft()`. This should speed up the performance.

Comment: `queue.pop(0)`  after `u = queue[0]`, inside the for loop that reads every neighbors of an unvisited node `queue.pop[0]` will drop all the nodes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about:

```
neighbour_list = [[4], [2, 5], [1, 3, 8], [2, 14], [0, 9], [1], [10, 12], [13], 
                 [2, 14], [4, 10, 15], [6, 9], [17], [6], [7, 19, 20], [3, 8], 
                 [9, 21], [22], [11, 18], [17, 19], [13, 18, 26], [13, 26], 
                 [15, 27], [16, 23], [22, 24, 28], [23, 25, 29], [24], 
                 [19, 20, 30, 31], [21], [23, 29], [24, 28], [26, 31], [26, 30]]

def bfs(neighbour_list, root):
    queue = []
    seen = set()

    queue.append(root)
    seen.add(root)

    while queue:
        cn = queue.pop(0)
        print("Current node: %d" % cn)
        for nn in neighbour_list[cn]:
            if nn not in seen:
                queue.append(nn)
                seen.add(nn)
                print("  Found %d" % nn)

    return seen

print bfs(neighbour_list, 0)
```

Which outputs:

```
Current node: 0
  Found 4
Current node: 4
  Found 9
Current node: 9
  Found 10
  Found 15
Current node: 10
  Found 6
Current node: 15
  Found 21
Current node: 6
  Found 12
Current node: 21
  Found 27
Current node: 12
Current node: 27
set([0, 4, 6, 9, 10, 12, 15, 21, 27])
```

Note that `set` isn't ordered.  So the result of this function will return all nodes reachable by `root`, but not in any sort of order of when the algorithm reached it.  If you want that, you could easily change `seen` to be a list.

Comment: what is the defference betwwen .append and .add ? @jedwards you append the list but add to the dictionnary?

Comment: You `.append()` to a list and `.add()` to a set. A set is an unordered collection whereas a list is ordered.

Comment: and whats the difference between queue.pop(0) and queue[0] dont they have the same result? @Tom Dalton

Comment: Sorry for the delay, `queue.pop(0)` returns the first element (same as `queue[0]`, but `pop` removes that element as well, simultaneously.

Comment: What's the point in doing expensive `pop(0)` instead of just `pop()` if you still return the component as an (unordered) set?

Answer (score 1):

This generator function will yield *all* connected components in a graph represented as an adjacency list. It also uses [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.deque) for a queue instead of a `list` for efficient pops from the beginning of the queue.

```
from collections import deque

def connected_components(graph):
    seen = set()

    for root in range(len(graph)):
        if root not in seen:
            seen.add(root)

            component = []
            queue = deque([root])

            while queue:
                node = queue.popleft()
                component.append(node)
                for neighbor in graph[node]:
                    if neighbor not in seen:
                        seen.add(neighbor)
                        queue.append(neighbor)
            yield component
```

Demo:

```
neighbour_list = [[4], [2, 5], [1, 3, 8], [2, 14], [0, 9], [1], [10, 12], [13],
                  [2, 14], [4, 10, 15], [6, 9], [17], [6], [7, 19, 20], [3, 8],
                  [9, 21], [22], [11, 18], [17, 19], [13, 18, 26], [13, 26],
                  [15, 27], [16, 23], [22, 24, 28], [23, 25, 29], [24],
                  [19, 20, 30, 31], [21], [23, 29], [24, 28], [26, 31], [26, 30]]

print(list(connected_components(neighbour_list)))
# [[0, 4, 9, 10, 15, 6, 21, 12, 27],
#  [1, 2, 5, 3, 8, 14],
#  [7, 13, 19, 20, 18, 26, 17, 30, 31, 11],
#  [16, 22, 23, 24, 28, 25, 29]]
```