# Python: Depth First Search 'maximum recursion depth exceeded'

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, recursion, depth-first-search

I have a recursive depth first search algorithm which takes in a black/white mask image, e.g.:

[image]

And outputs the x largest clusters of white pixels in that mask, e.g. (for x = 2):

[image]
[image]

The function is below:

```
def split_mask_into_x_biggest_clusters(input_mask, x):
    def generate_neighbours(point):
        neighbours = [
            (1, -1), (1, 0), (1, 1),
            (0, -1), (0, 1),
            (1, -1), (1, 0), (-1, 1)
        ]
        for neigh in neighbours:
            yield tuple(map(sum, zip(point, neigh)))

    def find_regions(p, points):
        reg = []
        seen = set()

        def dfs(point):
            if point not in seen:
                seen.add(point)
                if point in points:
                    reg.append(point)
                    points.remove(point)
                    for n in generate_neighbours(point):
                        dfs(n)

        dfs(p)
        return reg

    region = []
    data = np.array(input_mask)[:, :, 0]
    wpoint = np.where(data == 255)
    points = set((x, y) for x, y in zip(*wpoint))

    while points:
        cur = next(iter(points))
        reg = find_regions(cur, points)
        region.append(reg.copy())

    areas = {idx: area for idx, area in enumerate(map(len, region))}
    areas = sorted(areas.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    num = x

    masks = []
    for idx, area in enumerate(areas[:num]):
        input_mask = np.zeros((512, 512, 3))
        for x, y in region[area[0]]:
            input_mask[x, y] = [255, 255, 255]
        input_mask = input_mask.astype(np.uint8)
        masks.append(Image.fromarray(input_mask))

    return masks
```

My problem is that when I run it I get the following error: `maximum recursion depth exceeded`. Experimentally, I have tried increasing the recursion limit to `2000` then to `10000`(!):

```
sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)
```

This fixes the problem sometimes but not all the time (i.e. not when the clusters of white pixels are bigger).

What can I do to fix this problem? Thank you for any help.

Comment: Python isn't the best language for recursive methods.  Good ones implement tail-recursion, allowing for (almost) infinite recursion.  Python does not; hence it has a depth limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For big images you will always end up with this error.

You can either change you implementation to iterative DFS (which doesn't use recursion), or use BFS.

**UPD**

Implementation can be found [here (for iterative DFS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73837517/recursive-dfs-into-iterative-dfs-with-global-state)

[BFS implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26152380/connected-components-using-breadth-first-search)

Comment: Ok thanks. How would I convert the function find_regions() to an iterative dfs? I'm new to this kind of problem and unsure.